# How to add tags noautocollapse and NoClose in partstack for Eclipse 3.x perspectives

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am migrating 3.x eclipse RCP application to 4.x eclipse RCP application, we have requirement that when all views of specific folder will be closed, folder should not hide, What i understood from different articles that we have to add tags NoAutocollapse/NoClose in partStack, but i am not able to find out where should i add the tags in partStack so that folders created for perspective will be displayed even there is no view.

The perspective is created using plug-in extension and not using application model as it happens in eclipse 3.x, so is there any way to achieve the desired behavior without migrating the perspective to 4.x

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining the views using the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point then:

```
<view
  ....
  closeable="false"
  ....
```

in the view definition set the NoClose tag.

Comment: Using this view will no longer closable, but what i want is view should be closable not the folder defined for perspective. In 3.x we used isDurableFolder method to achive the behaviour but it is no longer supported in 4.x eclipse. In some threads they have mentioned that if you add NoAutocollapse/NoClose tags in partstack, folder will not dispose. I can achieve the behavior in Application model but i don't know how to use the feature with legacy perspectives(i.e. perspectives defined in 3.x)